# KendoUI - Clear MultiSelectDropdown onClick of button

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

How can I clear all MultiSelectDropdown values if I click on button / link.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <select multiple="multiple">
    <option>lorem ipsum</option>
    <option>lorem ipsum</option>
    <option>lorem ipsum</option>
  </select>
</div>

<a href="#" id="clear">Clear</a>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").kendoMultiSelect();   
});

$( document ).on( "click", "#clear", function(){
    $("select option").val("");
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/avz15vsr/5/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want clear selected values:

```
$(document).on( "click", "#clear", function(){
    $("select").data('kendoMultiSelect').value([]);
});
```

if you want to clear multiselect values:

```
$(document).on( "click", "#clear", function(){
    $("select").data('kendoMultiSelect').dataSource.data([]);
});
```

Comment: **@Gene R**... Perfecto... working great.. Thank you